# MongoDB Query Via PHP Driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm using a windows xampp server running PHP 5.4 and the PHP Mongo driver [from here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads).

I am querying the data using:

```
$results = $collection->find( array('league'=>'nba') );
  foreach ($results as $user) {
      var_dump($user);
      echo "</br>";
  }
```

Result:

```
array(5) { ["_id"]=> float(3.1677054844223E+18) ["league"]=> string(3) "nba" ["homeTeam"]=> string(10) "Washington" ...
```

I am converting the ID to a string:

```
$cursorID = new MongoID($result['_id']);
$gameLink = "<a href='/home/game/".$cursorID."'>".$cursorID."</a>";
```

which converts the ID from a float to this value: 50fde048f1568a204c0002a1
and trying to query for game details:

```
$gameID = new MongoID("50fde048f1568a204c0002a1"); //default
$con = new Mongo("mongodb://mongo.example.net"); // Connect to Mongo Server
$db = $con->selectDB('mydb');
$games = $db->games->find( array('_id'=>$gameID) );
```

But this does not return any results.

Thoughts on what could be going wrong?

Comment: what is MongoID() function?is that can reverse GameID (from 50fde048f1568a204c0002a1 to 3.1677054844223E+18) ?

Comment: Hmm your PHP driver does not seen to recognise `objectId`s at all for some unknown reason, what does the document look in your database? Can you paste a console output? Your _id may have changed type, if so then you cannot query by objectid

Comment: @Sammaye The console output is this: /* 0 */
{
  "_id" : NumberLong("3292523252251813670"),
  "league" : "ncaab",
  "gameTime" : "2013-01-07T18:30:00",
  "homeTeam" : "Cincinnati",
  "homeRank" : 14,
  "awayTeam" : "Notre Dame",
  "awayRank" : 21
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : NumberLong("6877183749884304734"),
  "league" : "ncaab",
  "gameTime" : "2013-01-07T19:00:00",
  "homeTeam" : "Penn St.",
  "awayTeam" : "Indiana",
  "awayRank" : 5
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yea some one has been fiddling with your `ObjectId`s and they are no longer `ObjectIds`.

You need to be using `ObjectId`s to query by them hence you cannot query by an `ObjectId`  (`MongoId` in PHP).

You should be able to query without wrapping the figure in a `MongoId` though since, if you have `native_long` set in your php.ini: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.configuration.php#ini.mongo.native-long (which it is by default in the newer drivers I bellieve), the driver should automatically convert `NumberLongs` to and fro for you.

So literally just query by the `$result['_id']` without putting it into a `MongoId`.

A word of caution though, using the _id you are not really that good and I would recommend you re-populate all your records again using `ObjectId` (`MongoId` in PHP) since this will be a lot more efficient and easier than the ID you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks. I had to move to a linux 64-bit php env to get this working properly. Also suggested the monogo team use objectID's.